# Start a pdf viewer from a Perl script

Tags: perl, daemon

I have to start a pdf viewer from a Perl script. The viewer should
become detached from the parent process and the terminal that the parent process was run from. If I close the parent or the terminal the 
viewer should still be kept running. I considered three approaches (using `evince` as the pdf viewer command):

1. Using `system` and `sh`:

   ```
   system 'evince test.pdf &';
   ```
2. Using `fork()`:

   ```
   $SIG{CHLD} = "IGNORE"; #reap children as they complete
   my $pid = fork();
   if ( $pid == 0 ) {
       exec 'evince', 'test.pdf';
   }
   ```
3. Using `Proc::Daemon`:

   ```
   use Proc::Daemon;
   my $daemon = Proc::Daemon->new(
       work_dir     => '/tmp/evince',
       child_STDOUT => '>>stdout.txt',
       child_STDERR => '>>stderr.txt',
   );
   my $pid = $daemon->Init();
   if ( $pid == 0 ) {
       exec 'evince', 'test.pdf';
   }
   ```

What would be the difference between these approaches? Which approach would you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
system 'evince test.pdf &';
```

In my experience, this is likely to really be:

```
system 'evince $pdf_file &';
```

If `$pdf_file` is user input, then we get shell-injection bugs, such as passing in a pdf name of `$(rm -rf /)` or even just `;rm -rf /`.  And what if the name has a space in it?  Well, you can avoid all that if you quote it, right?

```
system 'evince "$pdf_file" &';
```

Well, no, now all I have to do is give you a filename of `";rm -rf "/`.  And what if my pdf has a double quote in its name?  You could use single quotes, but the same problem comes up if the filename has single quotes in it, and the shell injection isn't really any harder.  You could come up with an elaborate shellify function that properly quotes a string all so that the shell can unquote it and get back to the original entry ... but that seems like so much more work than your other options, neither of which suffers from these problems.

```
$SIG{CHLD} = "IGNORE"; #reap children as they complete
my $pid = fork();
if ( $pid == 0 ) {
    exec 'evince', 'test.pdf';
}
```

Setting a global `$SIG{CHLD}` is nice and easy ... unless you need to handle other children as they die.  So only you can tell whether that's acceptable or not.  And, again in my experience, not even always then.  I've been bitten by this one - though rarely.  I had this mixed in with an application that, elsewhere, used [AnyEvent](https://metacpan.org/pod/AnyEvent), and managed to break AE's subprocess handling.  (The same would likely hold true if you mixed this with any event system, I just happened to be using AE.)

Also, this is missing the stdout and stderr redirects - and stdin redirect.  That's easy enough to add - inside your if, before the exec, just close and reopen the filehandles as you need, e.g.:

```
close STDOUT; open STDOUT, '>', '/dev/null';
close STDERR; open STDERR, '>', '/dev/null';
close STDIN;  open STDIN,  '<', '/dev/null';
```

No big deal.  However, Proc::Daemon does set up a few more things for you to ensure signals don't reach from one to the other process, in either direction.  This depends on how severe you need to get.

For most of my purposes, I've found #2 to be sufficient.  I've only reached for Proc::Daemon on a few projects, but that's where a) I have full control over the module installation, and b) it really matters.  Starting a pdf viewer wouldn't normally be such a case.

I avoid #1 at all costs - I have had some fairly significant bites with shell injection, and now try to avoid the shell at all times.

Comment: It would interesting if this could be related to the `nohup` and `setsid` commands